# How to upload/download file(images, excel, pdf etc.) using postgresql, php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

I try to make a website where people will have option to upload some files(excel, pdf etc.) and images. When they refresh the page I want them to see those files and have an option to download them.

I tried to google this for a long time and I am still not able to make it work. I read about bytea or blob option tried both. I even read and thought about using server file system.

This is as the far I've got.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=name;user=user;password=pass");
if (isset($_POST["insert"])) {
    $target_file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $img = fopen($target_file, 'r');
    $data = fread($img, filesize($target_file));
    //$file = pg_escape_bytea($data);
    //$file = pg_escape_bytea(addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])));
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES (?)';
    $ISp_Res = $db->prepare($sql);
    $ISp_Res->bindParam(1, $data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $ISp_Res->execute();
}
?>
<html>
   <head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
         <body>
        <br/><br/>
        <div class="container" style="width:500px;">
            <h3 align="center"></h3>
            <br/>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-info"/>
            </form>
            <br/>
            <br/>
                <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id DESC";
                $db = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=name;user=user;password=pass");
                $result = $db->prepare($query);
                $results = $result->execute();
                $results = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                foreach ($results as $row) {
                    ob_start();
                    fpassthru($row['data']);
                    $dat = ob_get_contents();
                    ob_end_clean();
                    //echo (base$row['data']);
                    //$dat = stream_get_contents($row['data']);
                    $dat = pg_unescape_bytea($dat);
                    //$dat = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($dat);
                    //echo "<img src='" . $dat . "'";
                    echo '<a href="'.$dat .'" download>You can download here '.$row['id'].'</a><br>';
                }
                ?>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now I was able to display an image on my website but it was in terrible quality. When I tried to download it there was a problem with corruption or missing parts.

Then I tried to unescape bytea from postgresql and I've got different problem that I cant download it at all.

As you can see in comment lines I tried some different things even combine some of them.

PS: I am an amateur so any comment will be helpful.
Its my first post so I am sorry If I broke any rules here.

EDIT:
Table I am trying to upload files.

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  data bytea,
  CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: Please post your database table structure. Also it is not the common/best way to store images directly in the database. You should store them on a filesystem.

Comment: I thought about to store them in the file system but I would have to save the path anyway to them right and I won't delete or update the images or other type of files so I decided to use database. I edited the post with table I use.